# split string in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have following text Banker's **XXXX YYYY~#0018800~MMMMM~0401**
 from sql table i need to filter only 0018800 from the text in select query how can i do it?
DBMS is SQL Server

Comment: Solution strictly depends on concrete DBMS you're using. Anyway, there were dozens of similar questions for almost every existed DBMS at StackOverflow, just use search. Here one possible solution: [How do I split a string so I can access item x?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andy Korneyev has pointed out, this would entirely depend on the DBMS.

For SQL Server you could use [`CHARINDEX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) and do something like the following:

```
DECLARE @Str VARCHAR(120)

SET @Str = 'XXXX YYYY~#0018800~MMMMM~0401'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@Str, CHARINDEX('#', @Str)+1, CHARINDEX('~', @Str)-3)
```

Or for MySQL you could use [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

Comment: this was very helpful, how can i check if the symbol # exist in this string?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
declare @test nvarchar(max) ='XXXX YYYY~#0018800~MMMMM~0401'

declare @index1 int = (charindex( '#', @test )+1);
declare @firstvariable nvarchar(max) =  substring( @test, @index1 ,LEN(@test) )

declare @index2 int = (charindex( '~', @test )-2);
select @index1,@firstvariable,@index2,substring( @firstvariable, 0,@index2 )
```

Comment: Product specific answer, to a question with no dbms tagged. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: It is for `Sql-server`